# Garbage output while downloading apk from server using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, android, apache, lamp

I'm using PHP to compile an app on an apache server based on the input provided by the user and then provide the app to them using the `readfile()` method. 
The problem that I'm facing is that instead of actually downloading the app, the .apk file is being opened as a text file. 
[image]

I have added the android app mime type in the PHP code. 
My php code is :

```
<?php
echo "Please wait while the app is being generated, it can take around 10 minutes for the build to finish.The completed app will be mailed to you ";

if(isset($_POST['timestamp']))
{
$uid = $_POST['timestamp'];
exec("sudo python /var/www/html/appgenserver.py $uid");

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");        //Adding or removing this hass no effect
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Foo.apk"');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("/var/www/html/".$uid."/releaseapk.apk");
exit();
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did was, rather than return the app from PHP script, I returned it URL to the AJAX call.

From there I navigated to that URL and the download initiated automatically.

PHP code :

```
<?php
{
    echo "http://server_ip/release/".$uid."/releaseapk.apk";
}
?>
```

Ajax cal :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
    url: "/test.php",
    data: { timestamp : timestamp },
        success: function(response){
          console.log("Success",response);
          window.location = response;
    }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it by removing the echo. Don't output to the page before the headers have been sent.

Comment: Have commented out the echo statement too. But still the same error.

Comment: I would start off with one of the examples on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php and get that to work, then add in additional things one at a time.

Comment: Thanks,
But I fixed it via another method and have answered the question

Answer (score 1):

The garbled output caused by the buffer is not clean, search for the output on the page before headers or Try using `ob_end_clean()` instead of `ob_clean()` and put it before your `header()`

Comment: Hey,
Doing this stopped the output of garbage code, but the download isn't getting initiated.